# Inconsistent dll linkage

Tags: dll, linker, warnings

Im getting several warnings saying I have inconsistent dll linkages despite me classifying the header of my dll like so:

```
#ifdef MY_ENGINE_EXPORTS
#define ENGINE __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define ENGINE __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

It works fine to get rid of the errors when I add MY_ENGINE_EXPORTS to the preprocessor definitions but I was under the impression that this should be done automatically on build/export. Am I wording it wrong? I included an underscore because the project is 2 words e.g "my engine". I've tried it as both MY_ENGINE_EXPORTS and MYENGINE_EXPORTS but neither seems to work.

As I say I can just add it to preprocessor definitions but it's bugging me why it doesn't behave as it should.

Comment: If you don't add it to the preprocessor definitions then you'll clearly run the risk of *not* having MY_ENGINE_EXPORTS #defined by accident for some translation units.  Nor did you explain how you made sure it was #defined.  Which of course explains the warning.

Comment: I'm realising how dumb this question was now but every topic I've seen has the #ifdef written in the same format of {projectname}_EXPORTS. I figured it was a predefined macro that the environment created for dll projects on build. It's annoying but I cant find the link I was looking at earlier that even stated it was automatic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I figured it was a predefined macro that the environment created for dll projects

Yes, that does happen when you use the Win32 Project template to get the DLL project started.  The wizard will automatically add the PROJECTNAME_EXPORTS preprocessor definition for you.

The wrinkle is that it cannot use a space in the symbol so it cannot use "MY PROJECT_EXPORTS".  It will **drop** the space and make it MYPROJECT_EXPORTS.  Which doesn't match with the one you used, MY_PROJECT_EXPORTS.  Nothing a quick Edit + Replace can't fix of course.

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you. The reason it hadn't created the preprocessor definition for me is because I started an empty project and then changed it to a dll project.

Comment: I think that half of all SO questions about MSVC would disappear if everybody stopped using the "Empty project" option.  No idea what is so attractive about it.